# CSS to highlight active link in a table of contents based on URL pattern

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div that contains a UL element with each of my page's table of contents.

Currently, I'm having to hardcode a special class on the active element (class="active"). However, I'm trying to see if I can use CSS3 to do the work by matching the href to the browser's current URL.

For example, if the href in the toc div's anchor matches the current URL of the page, add a special formatting to it.

Example URL: http://mysite.com/page-title/2

Markup:

```
<div class="toc">
    <h3>Table of Contents</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://mysite.com/page-title/">Part 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://mysite.com/page-title/2">Part 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://mysite.com/page-title/3">Part 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In the above example, I want to apply a special css formatting to the second list item element, since its HREF pattern has a match "/2" with the URL pattern.

If this is not doable via CSS, I can place it in my jQuery script if you can provide the jQuery code.

Comment: have to do it with script, would help if you make example a little more real world (details) ... does it need to be related to url for example

Comment: The real world example would be that you have a list of links on the page that are all underlined with a special color to identify them as links, however the current page is also in that list, and rather than applying a special class (class="active", for example) so that you can remove the underline, change the color and bold the element so that the user knows that's the link to the current page.

Comment: there are tons of posts here related to parsing url. Parse the url and use jQuery `filter()` to find your link(s)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with jQuery something like following should work;

```
var urlString = window.location; // or try window.location.pathname

$('a[href="' + urlString + '"]').addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for JavaScript here. Just add a class to the body tag that corresponds to the current page, and add that same class to the nav items. Then create a css rule for the matched sets like so:

```
<body class="products">
<div class="toc">
    <h3>Table of Contents</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://mysite.com/page-title/" class="products-nav">Product Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://mysite.com/page-title/2" class="home-nav">A More Dynamic Home Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://mysite.com/page-title/3" class="images-nav">Featured Images on Steroids</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and

```
<body class="home">
<div class="toc">
    <h3>Table of Contents</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://mysite.com/page-title/" class="products-nav">Product Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://mysite.com/page-title/2" class="home-nav">A More Dynamic Home Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://mysite.com/page-title/3" class="images-nav">Featured Images on Steroids</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

etc. then:

```
.products .products-nav, .home .home-nav, .images .images-nav {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```